# Name multiple variables in data frame, then use in formula

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 60 variables (plus y, the dependent variable, but that can be ignored for the first part of this question). I would like to first assign the colnames to be A1, A2, A3, ... A60. I would then like to use then in a linear model, adding one at a time. so I could run

```
lm(y ~ a1, data=dat)
lm(y ~ a1 + a2, data=dat)
```

but typing that 60 times is obviously undesirable. I assume there's an easier way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: see `setNames()` and `reformulate()` ...

Comment: might also be worth researching other methods to help with model selection, rather than creating 60 individual models. E.g, BMA, BIC, AIC Cp, etc

Comment: how about `lapply(2:ncol(mtcars), function(x) lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars[, 1:x]))`? it will keep everything in a nice list for you, too